# How to perform file encryption?

Tags: file, encryption

I'm writing my own encrypter (don't worry, I won't use it anywhere, it's just for learning how the things work). The encryption works well on binary data. My question is what is the best way to perform the encryption on a file. If I don't overwrite the original file, it will be recoverable. This way my operation is pointless. I can't just continuously overwrite the file, because if the process fail, the file will be corrupted.
I want the old, unencrypted file to be unrecoverable. What is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: "I want the old, unencrypted file to be unrecoverable." This is a very complex topic, and depends heavily on how the original file was stored and the resources of the party trying to recover it. In many cases, it cannot be practically solved, but in all cases it requires careful consideration of all of the hardware involved (I've done this for very high-value private keys; it's costly and requires a lot of planning). If this is your goal even in simple cases, you need to encrypt the file before writing it, not after.

Comment: Not kidding: after encrypting the file, transfer it to another computer and destroy the computer that created the original file (use a hard-drive shredder for the disks; a hard-drive shredder is like a paper shredder, but you put entire hard-drives in, then you incinerate the metal that comes out). I've done that. But for most problems, that's not really necessary. :D But don't write a file that you plan to encrypt later; encrypt it in the first place.

Comment: 1. Write the encrypted file to a new temporary file.  2.  Check that the new file is the expected size.  3. Securely delete the original file.  4. Rename the temporary encrypted file to the old file name, perhaps with "-ENC" added to the name.   Make *very* sure that you have thoroughly tested your code before you delete a real non-test file.  Keeping an offline backup of the original is good until you are sure everything works well.